# How to integrate Native ios and android sdk in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have to integrate one third party sdk in xamarin project.
They are providing the native sdk's for android and ios. I need to use them in Xamarin project to develop app for ios and android.

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin offers in depth documentation for linking native libraries.

[Linking native library iOS here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/) and [Binding a java Library here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/).

If you want to go further and use these sdk's in Xamarin.Forms you can make a wrapper in each platform dependent project and link them to your Forms project using [Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/).

Answer (score -2):

To use `Firebase Crashlytics` in your application follow the steps:

1. Install packages:  `Xamarin.firebase.iOS.Crashlytics` and `Xamarin.firebase.iOS.Core`
2. Download `GoogleService-Info.Plist` file and add it to your project.
3. Set the build action as "Bundle Resource".
4. Build the project and run.

Comment: The SO didn't specify a particular SDK... he meant it in general.